# Как сделать чтобы при нажатие на ссылку, открывалось твоё приложение?

Tags: android

Видел в приложениям, что кликая на ссылку, можно перейти в приложение. Как это делается??

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html

Comment: См ответ в вопросе-дубликате. Точно таким же способом можно и обычные ссылки в интернете открывать, если схемой указать `http` а хостом реальный домен